# form and ModelMultipleChoiceField with existing data

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-views

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367818/django-forms-and-modelmultiplechoicefield-when-working-with-existing-records) is very helpful on the subject.  However, I am working with a Class-Based View and am wondering how to accomplish the task of adding "selected" items to a ModelMultipleChoiceField when the queryset depends on an instance of the model with which I am working.

Models:

```
class OfferGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=False)
    priority = models.IntegerField(null=False, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('OfferGroup')
        ordering = ['priority', ]


class ConditionalOffer(AbstractConditionalOffer):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('auth.Group', verbose_name=_("User Groups"), blank=True)
    offer_group = models.ForeignKey(OfferGroup, related_name='offers', null=True)
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['priority', ]
```

Where AbstractConditionalOffer provides fields 'name', 'offer_type', start and end datetimes as well as foreign keys to other models.

Form:

```
class OfferGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    offers = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=ConditionalOffer.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.widgets.SelectMultiple(), required=False)

class Meta:
    model = OfferGroup
    fields = ('name', 'priority', 'offers')
```

*this form isn't really what I need, see below*

View:

```
class OfferGroupUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = OfferGroup
    template_name = 'dashboard/offers/offergroup_edit.html'
    form_class = OfferGroupForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard:offergroup-list')

    def save_offers(self, offer_group, form):
        selected_offers = form.cleaned_data['selected']
        for offer in selected_offers:
            offer_group.offers.add(offer, bulk=False)
        other_offers = form.cleaned_data['not_selected']
        for offer in other_offers & offer_group.offers.all():
            offer_group.offers.remove(offer)
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard:offergroup-list'))

    def form_valid(self, form):
        offer_group = form.save(commit=False)
        return self.save_offers(offer_group, form)
```

Now, the problem with this approach is that the queryset provided to OfferGroupForm doesn't provide any information about what offers are selected and what offers aren't for the instance of OfferGroup that I want to edit:

What I need is *something like*

```
og = OfferGroup.objects.get(pk=current offer_groups primary key)
selected = ConditionalOffers.objects.filter(offer_group=og)
other = ConditionalOffers.objects.exclude(offer_group=og)
```

So that when the view is rendered, offers with a foreign key to the current offer group (offer group being edited) appear as selected

Moreover, is there a way to do this in a Class Based View using a model form?

Forgive me if the code I have provided is a bit vague -- I tried to show the most salient snippets.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To simplify:  How can I create a MultiSelect widget with items selected based on whether they are referenced by a foreign key to the form model's object.

I can add all ConditionalOffers to the MultiSelect, how can I set some of them as selected?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to override the get_context_data method in the view:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # get the current obj
    obj = context.get('offergroup')
    # use the current object to get related objects
    qs = ConditionalOffer.objects.filter(offer_group=obj)
    # add context variables that can be used in the template
    context['selected'] = qs.values_list('name', flat=True)
    context['offers'] = ConditionalOffer.objects.all().exclude(offer_group=obj)
    return context
```